# `org-ellipsis` respected by `emacsclient` but not by `emacs`

Tags: org-mode, init-file, emacsclient, use-package

In my `emacs.d/init.el` I have:

```lisp
(use-package org
    ;; ...
    :custom
    (org-ellipsis " ▼")

    :custom-face
    (org-ellipsis ((t (:foreground "#665" :underline nil))))
    ;; ...
)
```

Oddly, I see the correct  `▼` when I am running `emacsclient`, but when in `emacs` I still see `...`.

I seen the same issue in Emacs 27.1, 27.2 and 28.0.50.

Any idea what might be the issue here?

---

Edit: I know that there can be [code that runs only for emacsclient fraimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064390), but I can't think of any such code that I might run, that may affect the rendering of org-ellipsis, or if there is such code - how to find it.
Grepping for `after-make-frame-functions` and `server-visit-hook` did not yield anything of interest.

Comment: Do you mean that when you first run `emacs` on an Org buffer, you see `...` as `org-ellipsis` and then doing the same thing with `emacsclient`, it displays ` ▼` as `org-ellipsis` ? If so, this is quite odd, because AFAIK `emacs` is the one which loads your `init.el`, OTOH `emacsclient` merely connect to an Emacs server.

Comment: My `emacsclient` command is `/usr/local/bin/emacsclient --create-frame --alternate-editor=""`, and my `emacs` command is `/usr/local/bin/emacs`.